# silverlight 3 minimize to tray + drag and drop from desktop?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Does anyone know if silverlight 3 will support minimize to tray and drag and drop from desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Not SL3. You can go "Out Of Browser", but there is no desktop interaction because of the sandbox.

SL4 does have some features that allow popups (toast) - this is likely to be released middle of next year. See www.silverlight.net for further information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Mark's answer

No drag and drop in SL3 but SL4 Controls can now be set up as drop targets - there is a good demo of this by Jesse Liberty over at http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/silverlight-controls-drop-targets/